# I'm getting nothing here in main activity

Tags: android

[image: **enter image description here**]

I'm doing it as a college project using Card View and List View.

The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView. This widget is a container for displaying large data sets that can be scrolled very efficiently by maintaining a limited number of views. Use the RecyclerView widget when you have data collections whose elements change at runtime based on user action or network events.

The RecyclerView class simplifies the display and handling of large data sets by providing:

Layout managers for positioning items
Default animations for common item operations, such as removal or addition of items
You also have the flexibility to define custom layout managers and animations for RecyclerView widgets.

My main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="sonu.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/ToolbarMain">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_below="@id/ToolbarMain"
        android:divider="@null">

    </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>





<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivMain"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvMain"
            android:text="Timetable"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivMain"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:text="Description"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvMain"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivMain"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvClick"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="Click here"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ivMain"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package sonu.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupUiViews();
        initToolbar();

    }
    private void setupUiViews(){
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.ToolbarMain);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMain);


    }
    private void initToolbar(){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TimeTable App");

    }
    private void setUpListView(){
        String[] title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Main);
        String[] description = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Description);
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, title, description);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }
    public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context myContext;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private TextView title, description;
        private  String[] titleArray;
        private  String[] descriptionArray;
        private ImageView imageView;

        public SimpleAdapter(Context myContext, String[] titleArray, String[] descriptionArray){
            this.myContext=myContext;
            this.titleArray=titleArray;
            this.descriptionArray=descriptionArray;
            layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(myContext);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return titleArray.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return titleArray[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView==null){
                convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_single_item, null);


            }
            title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMain);
            description=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMain);

            title.setText(titleArray[position]);
            description.setText(descriptionArray[position]);

            if (titleArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Timetable")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.timetable);

            }else if (titleArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Subjects")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.subjects);
            }else if (titleArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Faculty")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.teachers);
            }else if (titleArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("resource")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.resource);

            }
            return convertView;


        }
    }
}
```

and now my strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string-array name="Main">
        <item> Timetable </item>
        <item> Subjects </item>
        <item> Faculty </item>
        <item> Resources </item>

    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Description">
        <item> Description 1</item>
        <item> Description 2</item>
        <item> Description 3</item>
        <item> Description 4</item>

    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: try to   use first  initToolbar() method then  setupUiViews();

Comment: okk let me do that. thanks btw.

Comment: i'm not sure if it is an copy and paste error or what ever, but your cardview definition is outside of your root element in main_activity.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your oncreate method should be like this.Initializing views first then toolbar then accessing views and setting adapter.Also seeing your code I think you havent called  setUpListView().Try to add that and check again.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupUiViews();
    initToolbar();
    setUpListView();
}
```

Comment: THANKS. it worked for me. i was just missing to call that setUpListView(); method. thanks a lot friend

Comment: ya when I pasted your code in studio I saw that..You dint call that method..Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

And add com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0 cardview dependency in your gradle. If by default toobar is there then you need not to call initToolbar() method.